# Connect two different Database with one application in ASP.NET

Tags: mysql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to connect Sql server and MySql database with my application in Visual studio. Is it possible to connect multiple database with one application.

Because i have to import data from mysql in my application. There is lot data in mysql database. So, i am thinking to connect to mysql as well as my current database (sql server). is there any way, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. it is possible.

Comment: Yes. Give it a go.

Comment: "Is it possible to connect multiple database with one application." Yes. Very straightforward - two connection strings, two different connections. If they're actually two different platforms like MySQL and SQL-Server, then you may need separate code libraries to access them, unless you use an ORM or other abstraction layer which can handle both without changes. Basically it's no different to using one database, except that you have 2. Same again if you have 20. You just need to go and do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set multiple Connection String in the Web Config file and just reference it based on your requirements.. see below

Web Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="SQLServerDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=<SERVER NAME>;Initial Catalog=<DATABASE NAME>;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="MySqlDBConnectionString" connectionstring="Data Source=00.0.0.0;Initial Catalog=<DATABASE NAME>;User Id=user;Password=pass" providername="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then to get reference with different connections:

```
public  string SQLServerDBConnstring()
{       
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerDBConnectionString"].ToString();        
}

public string MySqlDBConnstring()
{
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlDBConnectionString"].ToString();
}
```